# Calling controller from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I am trying to call a controller from directive....Here is the code which i am writing

```js
penApp.directive('enpo', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
 
    scope: {
      info: '=',
   dragEvent: '&dragParent'
 },
 templateUrl: 'enpo.html',
 link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  
  var circleDiv = element.find(".circle")
  element.droppable({
   
   
  })
  element.draggable({
   handle: ".circle",
   drag: function( event, ui ) {
    
    scope.dragEvent();
   }
  });
  var eDiv = element.find(".temp")
  $(eDiv).draggable({revert: true});
 }
};

})
```

and this is the code for .html file

```html
<div class="row ">
 <div id="n_div" class="col-xs-12 dd_area">
  <end-point drag-parent="drawLine()" ng-repeat="info in stageObjectArray" info="info"></end-point>
 </div>
 </div>
```

and this is the function i have written in controller

```js
$scope.drawLine = function(){
 
  console.log("Called thsssssse function")
 }
```

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here...can anyone please guide...the controller function is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be a little clearer what each piece of code is?

Hope this will help you out:

Looks to me like you have created a directive with a link function and an html template.

From the HTML template you are trying to call the function in a controller that you have written, however I do not see that you are attaching the controller to the HTML, where you want to use it.

Try adding ng-controller="MyController" (MyController being the name of your controller which contains the $scope.drawline function) to your HTML, as follows:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div id="n_div" class="col-xs-12 dd_area" ng-controller="MyController">
        <end-point drag-parent="drawLine()" ng-repeat="info in stageObjectArray" info="info"></end-point>
    </div>
 </div>
```

BTW, I don't see where you are actually using your 'enpo' directive in your HTML. I am assuming that you are in fact calling it, but omitted that part of the code here.